# How to automatically indicate word wrap in print in Microsoft Word?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2011

I'm curious as to whether there's a way to have Word automatically indicate in Normal mode where it's inserting line breaks?  I'm making a printout with code in it and it doesn't have to look pretty, but it would be nice if the word wrapping were indicated automatically.  Specifically, I'm using Word for Mac 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft Word has no such feature. As an alternative you can add list numbering or bullet points to your paragraphs of code (assuming you are using a special style for code you can add it to this style). This way it is easier to see what lines are wrapped and what are new.